# Is a UK FLR (M) Extension Visa added to the existing time, or started from now?

Tags: visa, uk-visa

I'm a UK citizen, and my wife is a non-EEA citizen. She is applying to extend her spouse visa via FLR(M). Her current spouse visa expires in January 2018.

Our question is, would the extension be applied from January 2018, or from the date it is approved?

As my wife will apply for indefinite leave to remain after 5 years in total, that might change our decision to apply for the extension now, as we would waste several months of the current visa.

We're confident the application will be approved as we meet the criteria, it's just a question of how the extension is granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd FLR leg runs from the decision date, so you keep the current visa active until 28 days before it expires. You will 'waste time' anyway because the decisions are not instantaneous. It can take up to 4 - 5 months unless you use the premium service.

---

The [FLR(M) Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/601827/FLR_M_Guidance_Notes_-_April_2017.pdf) advises applying 28 days before the expiry date of her current visa.

The extension moves the date forward, but will start from the date of issue.